# magento 2 Cannot instantiate interface PsrExt\Log\LoggerInterface

Tags: magento2, home-page, magento2-enterprise, psr-logger

Magento 2 enterprise edition getting error

```
Cannot instantiate interface PsrExt\Log\LoggerInterface vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:57 Stack trace: #0
```

I tried search keyword psrext but no luck

can any guide me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the php-psr extension ( most likely ). Try disabling the extension. This is a known behaviour under PHP7.4 and should be fixed in 8.x.

Use the ObjectManager or di.xml to register PsrExt\Log\LoggerInterface to return a default logger instance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Psr\Log\LoggerInterface. So I guess somewhere it is used wrong. Try looking in custom modules. Also can try to remove all in vendor folder and just do composer install again. Maybe there was some text pasted by mistake. If no luck, then add breakpoint here vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:57 and use xdebug to find where it starts and where it comes from.

Comment: I tried this did not find any file.
 I used grep -iRl "PsrExt"

Comment: disabled all core and third party still it showing error

Comment: Disable won't help. Need remove. If can't remove, try xdebuging. Without code can't help more

Comment: trying xdebug but not getting any info in that phpstrome +xdebug

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dnf -y remove php74-php-pecl-psr-devel.x86_64
sudo yum -y remove php74-php-pecl-psr-devel.x86_64
```

Note: command, package name can be different.
Example for Redhat-like distributive.
Main focus: removing **php psr**.

> Cannot instantiate interface PsrExt\Log\LoggerInterface#0 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> #1 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
> #2 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
> #3 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
> #4 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
> #5 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
> #6 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> #7 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
> #8 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
> #9 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
> #10 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
> #11 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
> #12 vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
> #13 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(216): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
> #14 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(180): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->_applyDecorators()
> #15 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->create()
> #16 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Pool.php(151): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->_initialize()
> #17 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/FrontendPool.php(87): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool->get()
> #18 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Type/Config.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool->get()
> #19 vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config->_getFrontend()
> #20 vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(73): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->load()
> #21 vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load()
> #22 vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(191): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager()
> #23 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create()
> #24 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(127): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct()
> #25 vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(184): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create()
> #26 vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(84): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->initObjectManager()
> #27 bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
> #28 {main}

[-> source](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35019#issuecomment-1022096607)